# Get Cannot POST /register after deploy to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my backend to Heroku. The application works fine when using local server and database. The deploy was successful and I used `Heroku addons` to add a PostgreSQL database and created tables. However when I try to run the `register` function with Heroku backend in http://localhost:3000/. I receive an error of `Cannot POST /register`. Any idea what would lead to this status 404?

#### What I did / suspect

- Tested the register function in local server and it works fine.
- receive the msg "It is working" when I run `Heroku open`, the msg is from
  `app.get('/', (req, res)=> { res.send('it is working!')})` in `server.js`
- Though I saw the message, however I notice that the process is existed in the Heroku logs..

`heroku logs --tail`

```
2021-01-27T10:44:45.620235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-01-27T10:44:45.703716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

- Tried to see if it's due to security issue but still failed.

Method 1

- adding `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;`

Method 2

```
const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      connectionString : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      //ssl : true,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
});
```

#### Source Code

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');

const register = require('./controllers/register');
const signin = require('./controllers/signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/profile')
const image = require('./controllers/image')


const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      connectionString : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl : true,
    }
});

const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res)=> { res.send('it is working!')})
app.post('/signin', signin.handleSignin(db, bcrypt))
app.post('/register', (req,res) => { register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt)})
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => { profile.handleProfile(req, res, db)})
app.put('/image', (req, res) => { image.handleImage(req, res, db)})
app.post('/imageurl',(req,res) => { image.handleApiCall(req,res)})


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT}`);
})
```

`register.js` backend

```
const handleRegister = (req,res,db,bcrypt) => {
    const {email, name, password} = req.body;
    if (!email || !name || !password){
        return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
    }
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
        db.transaction(trx => {
            trx.insert({
                hash: hash,
                email: email
            })
            .into('login')
            .returning('email')
            .then(loginEmail => {
                return trx('users')
                .returning('*')
                .insert({
                    email: loginEmail[0],
                    name: name,
                    joined: new Date()
                })
                .then(user => {
                    res.json(user[0]);
                })
            })
            .then(trx.commit)
            .catch(trx.rollback)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
}

module.exports = {
    handleRegister: handleRegister
};
```

`heroku logs --tail`

```
2021-01-27T10:44:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user xxx@gmail.com
2021-01-27T10:44:44.417790+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 759e2483 by user xxx@gmail.com
2021-01-27T10:44:44.417790+00:00 app[api]: Release v20 created by user xxx@gmail.com
2021-01-27T10:44:44.636591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-01-27T10:44:44.638813+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-01-27T10:44:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-27T10:44:45.620235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-01-27T10:44:45.703716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-01-27T10:44:46.785854+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-01-27T10:44:48.903138+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-27T10:44:48.903166+00:00 app[web.1]: > face-detection-api@1.0.0 start /app
2021-01-27T10:44:48.903167+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-01-27T10:44:48.903167+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-27T10:44:49.286019+00:00 app[web.1]: Our app is running on port 23242
2021-01-27T10:44:49.661307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-27T10:45:06.408088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=xxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxx fwd="xxx" connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=181 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, it seems that the POST request you mentioned has not received by the handleRegister backend.

Can you try to return a message to make sure the handleRegister is working correctly?

---